# How to make surefire-report link to the failure line in the source code

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to make the generated surefire reports, link to the line in source code, where the error took place. I have followed everything mentioned on the plugins documentation over [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/cross-referencing.html).

Although it links to the correct source file, it doesn't link to the line number.

**Should be like this**

[image: Sample image with the line number]

**but is instead like this**

[image: Generated surefire report without the line number]

Comment: Have you put the maven-jxr-plugin first in the report configuration and in the build configuration?

Comment: Yes. The maven-jxr-plugin links the report to the source file, just not to the exact line number.

Comment: Have you defined both in the reporting area?

Comment: Would be helpful if you add your pom.xml, or at least, the reporting section